# Use custom RejectedExecutionHandler

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

While using `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` I wanted to try to execute a rejected task once more.
Is it really possible? I have heard of `RejectedExecutionHandler` interface. There are many available(known) instances of the interface(RejectedExecutionHandler) such as ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy, ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy, ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy, ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy etc. but the problem is that they do not allow to retry the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to retry the execution of the rejected task.
The best way to retry the execution is to use an alternate executor.
You may declare a custom RejectedExecutionHandler class simply like as you do this with other interfaces.
Here are some code samples:

```
public class MyRejectedExecutionHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler {



@Override
public void rejectedExecution(Runnable worker, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(worker.toString()+" is Rejected");

    System.out.println("Retrying to Execute");
    try{
        //Re-executing with alternateExecutor
        MainClass.alternateExecutor.execute(worker);
        System.out.println(worker.toString()+" Execution Started");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Failure to Re-exicute "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

You can find more details about this at: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/rejectedexecutionhandler/java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionhandler-example/

Comment: This is a possible solution, but pretty rare that it would be required.  If one pool is rejecting execution it is because you shouldn't be passing tasks to it.

Comment: the rejection may also occure because of other issues like, if the local memory bounds are exceeded, or if the executor was shutdown prior.

Answer (score 7):

Below is a retry-enabled RejectedExecutionHandler that does not require an 
additional ThreadPoolExecutor. It's is more practical: when a task was rejected, the rejected task will be put into the workerQueue of ThreadPoolExecutor in blocking mode, which makes the task submitter wait some time before the ThreadPoolExecutor can process any more tasks.

```
new RejectedExecutionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            if (!executor.isShutdown()) {
                try {
                    executor.getQueue().put(r);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    ;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Excellent answer. One question: this behavior will only be retry-enabled if we are using BlockingQueue, right?

Comment: A worker normally gets rejected when the queue is full and at that time there is no point adding the same worker into the queue again. Sometimes this could run recursively...

Comment: You might have solved my problem, this looks similar to what I was trying to do.

Comment: Maybe to solve the inifinite recursion you should add a retry count.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add few points to the comment by @Viscent Huang.
First, this solution makes sense only if your `ThreadPoolExecutor` is using `BlockingQueue`.
Second, this solution also provides risk that you may have a deadlock in case your threadpool is full because you're inserting runnable in a blocking manner in a threadpool which might be already filled.
For example this code may easily cause such problem:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> {
            // some computation intensive task
        }, executors
).thenAcceptAsync(
        res -> {
            // handling the result
        }, executors);
```

What I suggest is to handle rejected threads in a separate threadpool to avoid deadlock. So finally your code may look like this:

```
public class CustomRejectedExecutionHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    private final Executor rejectedExecutionThread = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        rejectedExecutionThread.execute(() -> {
            try {
                executor.getQueue().put(r);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle exception
            }
        });
    }
}
```